# Simple DMZ Question Regarding Physical Hardware

Tags: firewalls, dmz

So when talking about at setting up a DMZ, if you are currently running a web server, app server, and a database server on the same physical host, you need to migrate them to separate physical hosts and setup firewall rules between them? It isn't something that can be done virtually on the same physical host... except maybe if you are running VMware and have each on separate virtual machine with virtual firewalls between them?

Comment: It all depends on what you want to protect. The answer is 'sure' to all your questions, but it depends.

Comment: I am trying to protect the salary and bonus information of all my clients. Sensitive information. The intranet users should have access to the raw data for crunching. External should not have access to the raw data, but should be able to crunch data using it. Not nearly as specific and in depth a crunch as the intranet users need, but just to get customized general data.

Comment: Oh, and there are two web apps. The one the intranet users use and the one the external users use.

Comment: The normal DMZ configuration looks like Internet<-->firewall<-->DMZ<-->firewall<-->Intranet.  You would probably want your web server and external app server in the DMZ, and your database and internal app server on your intranet.